# Why is array = Array(10).fill(Array(20).fill(-1)) not the same as array [[-1,..,-1], ..., [-1,..,-1]]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I tried to create a 2-dimensional array in javascript. (Actually, the code is written in typescript and will be used to style DOM Elements with Angular2 but, as far as I am concerned, it shouldn't have any effect on the result in this case.)

First way:

```
arrayi = Array(10).fill(Array(20).fill(-1))
```

Second way:

```
array = [];
for(var i: number = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    array[i] = [];
    for(var j: number = 0; j< 20; j++) {
          array[i][j] = -1;
    }
}
```

If I call `array[1][2] = 2;` it does what I expected, what means setting one element in the 2-dimensional array to 2.

However, if I call `arrayi[1][2] = 2;` every element `arrayi[x][2]` will be set to 2. (With x element {0,1,2,...,9})

Why is that? I don't understand it. So it would be nice if someone could explain it to me.

The arrays are defined as `array: number[][]` and `arrayi: number[][]` in typescript.

Comment: @evolutionxbox As the post states: if I call `arrayi[1][2] = 2;` every element `arrayi[x][2]` will be set to 2. (With x element {0,1,2,...,9})

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arrayi = Array(10).fill(Array(20).fill(-1))` fills with **the same** array.

You can even rewrite it like this

```
const arr1 = Array(20).fill(-1)

const arrayi = Array(10).fill(arr1)

console.log(arrayi.every(item => item === arr1)) //true
```

Comment: So... when I do `arr = Array(2).fill([1,2,3])` it is pseudo for `temp = [1,2,3]; arr = [temp, temp]`? Got it now I guess. It is because the array will be linked instead of duplicated right? Thank you very much.

Comment: Kinda. It uses the same value for every index. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you create one instance of array with 20 elements and put this single instance into each element of root array